# Printing a Specified File Exercise Java

Tags: java, printing

Taking a beginners course in Java and I am stuck on one of the exercises. We're meant to print the text within a specific file, which we can find via the file's name which was inputted by a user. In our previous exercise, we learned that

```
    try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(Paths.get("data.txt")))
```

would find the text within the file "data.txt", but I am unsure about how to convert this into finding any file name inputted by the user.

More details below.

**Exercise:** Write a program that asks the user for a string, and then prints the contents of a file with a name matching the string provided. You may assume that the user provides a file name that the program can find.

The exercise template contains the files "data.txt" and "song.txt", which you may use when testing the functionality of your program. The output of the program can be seen below for when a user has entered the string "song.txt". The content that is printed comes from the file "song.txt". Naturally, the program should also work with other filenames, assuming the file can be found.

**My code so far is:**

```
    import java.nio.file.Paths;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class PrintingASpecifiedFile {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
            System.out.println("Which file should have its contents printed?");
    
            String fileName = scanner.nextLine();
    
          //try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(Paths.get(fileName))) {
            try(scanner = Paths.get(fileName)) {    // this part of the code is underlined red
        
                while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
                    String output = scanner.nextLine();
                    System.out.println(output);
                }
        
            } 
            catch (Exception e){
                  System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }

          }
       }
```

I have tried searching how to add a new scanner as that was a suggestion but every time I've tried it gets an error. Also the "try" section is underlined red and cannot seem to figure out why. The underlined red part says **variables in try-with-resources are not supported in -source 8**

If anyone has tips, I would really appreciate it! Thank you!

Comment: and if it had been supported, you would have got a different error in that line... `scanner` is not a `Path`...

Comment: Look at [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html) you will see that `Paths.get()` returns a `Path` and not a `Scanner` so you cannot do `scanner = Paths.get(fileName)`.

Comment: You should create another scanner with another name. `scanner` already exist so just uncomment your `try` line and replace `Scanner scanner` by `Scanner anotherScanner`. You also need to replace `scanner` in your `try-catch` by `anotherScanner`. PS : Don't forget to close your scanner.

Comment: Solved it,replaced 

            try(scanner = Paths.get(fileName)) {    
                while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
                    String output = scanner.nextLine();
                    System.out.println(output);
                }

**with**

try (Scanner userInputScan = new Scanner(Paths.get(fileName))) {
            while (userInputScan.hasNextLine()){
                String row = userInputScan.nextLine();
                System.out.println(row);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used one `Scanner` for reading the file path from the console.

You need an *other* `Scanner` (or reader alternative) for reading the file.

```
try (Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(fileName)) {
try (Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(Paths.get(fileName))) {
```